# Does POSTMAN support http2 request

Tags: python-3.x, postman

I am trying to send http2 request using postman. However, when my server receives the request gives error:

```
handle: <Handle _SelectorSocketTransport._read_ready()>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncio/events.py", line 145, in _run
    self._callback(*self._args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 721, in _read_ready
    self._protocol.data_received(data)
  File "/home/deesharm/jetconf/jetconf/jetconf/rest_server.py", line 76, in data_received
    events = self.conn.receive_data(data)
  File "/home/deesharm/jetconf/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h2/connection.py", line 1448, in receive_data
    .. versionchanged:: 2.0.0
  File "/home/deesharm/jetconf/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h2/frame_buffer.py", line 52, in add_data
    raise ProtocolError("Invalid HTTP/2 preamble.")
h2.exceptions.ProtocolError: Invalid HTTP/2 preamble.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Currently, Postman doesn't support HTTP/2.

https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/2701

Answer (score 12):

As of late 2022, Postman still does not support HTTP2.

A workaround is to click the "Code" icon (looks like `</>` ) to generate the cURL command, add the `--http2` command line flag, then copy/paste it into the terminal:

> [image: click the code icon to get the cURL script]

Works well with any mac / linux terminal as well as WSL2 on Windows. You can also provide the `--verbose` flag to cURL to make sure HTTP2 is working as expected.

Comment: I had to include the --http2-prior-knowledge option for cURL to send an HTTP 2 request.

Answer (score 3):

I created a GUI tool that you can use to send HTTP requests, with support for HTTP/2 and HTTP/3. It has full compatibility with existing Postman collections and environments.

https://github.com/alexandrehtrb/Pororoca

Comment: I really like it. Thanks!

Comment: man your app is really good, keep it up! @Alexandre